# How to hide sub-pages using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prestashop-1.6

I have a shopping cart page which contain four sub pages
(Shopping Bag, Contact information, Shipping Method, Payment Method) which looks like this:

[image]

A user can navigate through like normal navigation, so I want this nav to be hidden in a shopping cart in general and show only when user goes to the next step in cart process.

Note: I am using hash to navigate thorough this navs

Here is nav html:

```
<div class="box-steps">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs bs-wizard" style="border-bottom:0;" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li class="bs-wizard-step active">
            <a href="#box-order-one" id="step-one" data-toggle="tab">{l s='Koszyk' mod='threepagecheckout'}</a>
               <img src="http://localhost:8080/modules/threepagecheckout/views/css/../../views/img/right-arrow.png">
        </li>
        <li class="bs-wizard-step">
            <a href="#box-order-two" data-toggle="tab">{l s='Dane kontaktowe' mod='threepagecheckout'}</a>
            <img src="http://localhost:8080/modules/threepagecheckout/views/css/../../views/img/right-arrow.png">

        </li>
        <li class="bs-wizard-step">
            <a href="#box-order-three" data-toggle="tab">{l s='Dostawa' mod='threepagecheckout'}</a>
            <img src="http://localhost:8080/modules/threepagecheckout/views/css/../../views/img/right-arrow.png">

        </li>
        <li class="bs-wizard-step">
            <a href="#box-order-four" data-toggle="tab">{l s='Sposób płatności' mod='threepagecheckout'}</a>

        </li>
        <li class="stretch"></li>
    </ul><!-- end Box header right -->
</div>
<!-- end Box Header steps -->
```

Here is JS I have so far:

```
function hideNavbar() {
    if (window.location.hash == "#box-order-one") {
        $('.bs-wizard').hide();
    } else {
        $('.bs-wizard').show();
    }

}
function linkBackToBoxOne() {
    $('#step-one').click(function () {
        window.location.hash = "#box-order-one";
        $('.bs-wizard').hide();
    });
}
```

For reference: to navigate to the main shopping cart I use this link

```
http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc
```

which displays orders and navs in general, I want navs to be hidden immediately when visiting this page.

My method hides navs only when I visit this links

```
http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc#box-order-one
http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc#box-order-two
http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc#box-order-three
http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc#box-order-four
```

Googled almost 3hrs nothing worked please I need your help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?!

```
function hideNavbar() {
//start hiding all steps
$('.bs-wizard-step').hide();

if (window.location.hash == "#box-order-one") {
    $( "#box-order-one" )
        .prevUntil( "li" )
            $('.bs-wizard-step').show();
}
```

}

https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

of course: id="" should be in < li> tags... but that's the way

Comment: Flexicon This hides at start but when I go to next step still it hide the navs, needs to hide aat this location: `window.location.pathname ==="index.php?controller=order-opc"` and show on this path `window.location.pathname ==="index.php?controller=order-opc#box-order-two or three or four " etc`

Comment: ok. prevUntil is to .show() all links before the active one, that you check with Bricky's solution.. You should combine prevUntil() nextUntil(). This function is to do "something" (hide,show...) before or after a specific DOM node taken by the URL "position". Let me know.

Comment: I am just begginer bro , can you show me how to do that , am not good at all in javascript :(  I am green as hell :( thanks for the help though]

Comment: well done! Should be usefull having your example code ;)

Comment: flex changed the hash value instead of this window.location.hash == "#box-order-one  changed to this window.location.hash == "#box-order-two,  this worked

Answer (score 1):

If you want the nav to be hidden on the URL `http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc` you need to add a check in your Javascript for that URL. Since that page doesn't have a hash, you'll need to use something other than `window.location.hash`.

For example you could use `window.location.pathname` which gives you everything after the domain - in this case it would be `index.php?controller=order-opc`

```
function hideNavbar() {
    if (window.location.hash === "#box-order-one" || window.location.pathname ==="index.php?controller=order-opc") {
        $('.bs-wizard').hide();
    } else {
        $('.bs-wizard').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: let me check , I will be back sooon

Comment: Bricky still this does not hide it :(

Comment: Make sure your javascript is wrapped in a document.ready function as well. Your JS might be executing before anything on the page is loaded.
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I am calling function like this : ` 
 $(document).ready(function () {
 hideNavbar();
 linkBackToBoxOne();
 
 )}`